# /system/bin/mediaserver and /system/bin/drmserver dont want these but Android disagrees

Tags: adb, boot, performance, media-scanner, drm

I used this link [Use Adb to disable Media Server](http://geeknizer.com/fix-android-media-server-scanner-sdcard-cpu-battery-drain/)

hoping to permanenenly disable the battery hogging media server process . It did not work Mediaserver still runs on my Android 4.4 Jiayu S3 phone as `/system/bin/mediaserver` and I found another just as pricky process called `/system/bin/drmserver` which shows up on `adb # top` .
So I mounted the `/system` in RW mode and removed `-x` from them both. 
After that I killed the existing processes for these binaries. The phone just froze .  After a force restart it will NOT BOOT until I restored the `-x` bit again ( restored execute ) .
What do these do . How do I  ensure they don't run if they are not needed.

Comment: I believe you should add a link to your previous  question which is the actual problem you're trying to solve I think.

Comment: You are right. Probably didn't need to be a new question but there was so much information so I thought maybe a new question would bring that out thank you again

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old question but I have an answer for anyone wondering.If you do not care about playing DRM-protected content, just replace /system/bin/drmserver with an executable file that does nothing (e.g. just sleeps forever). Example: [File someone made for a Magisk module that disabled DRM](https://gitlab.com/Atrate/magisk-drm-disabler/blob/master/magisk-drm-disabler/system/bin/drmserver)